# Как включить поддержку php на VPS

Tags: apache, vps, httpd

Здравствуйте. Заказал сервер VPS для сайта. Пытаюсь настроить его для сайта.
В файл **httpd.conf** добавляю запись о домене:

```
NameVirtualHost ип_сервера:80
<VirtualHost ип_сервера:80>
ServerAdmin adnin@domain.ru
DocumentRoot /var/www/ru638561/data/www/domain.ru
ServerName domain.ru
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.htm
ErrorLog /var/www/ru638561/data/www/domain.ru/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/ru638561/data/www/domain.ru/access_log common
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
</VirtualHost>
```

В итоге получается когда я перехожу на свой сайт(domain.com например), я вижу php код странички, так как php не обрабатывает. 
Я добавляю строку **AddHandler php-cgi .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml** в блок VirtualHost, получается так:

```
NameVirtualHost ип_сервера:80
<VirtualHost ип_сервера:80>
ServerAdmin adnin@domain.ru
DocumentRoot /var/www/ru638561/data/www/domain.ru
ServerName domain.ru
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.htm
ErrorLog /var/www/ru638561/data/www/domain.ru/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/ru638561/data/www/domain.ru/access_log common
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddHandler php-cgi .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml
</VirtualHost>
```

И теперь если я перехожу на свой сайт - **Not Found** *The requested URL /php-bin/php/index.php was not found on this server.*

В чем проблема?
Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если под VPS понимается, что у вас честно выданная виртуалка с установленной операционкой и рутовым доступом (а не какой-нибудь самодельный/самопальный конструктор) -- то вообще-то во всех более-менее современных дистрибутивах всё это уже вшито в дистрибутивы.

Например, в центосе при установке httpd и php (`yum install httpd php`) добавлятся файл `/etc/http/httpd.conf/php.conf` c такими строками:

```
#
# PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting language which attempts to make it
# easy for developers to write dynamically generated webpages.
#
<IfModule prefork.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule worker.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5-zts.so
</IfModule>

#
# Cause the PHP interpreter to handle files with a .php extension.
#
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php

#
# Add index.php to the list of files that will be served as directory
# indexes.
#
DirectoryIndex index.php

#
# Uncomment the following line to allow PHP to pretty-print .phps
# files as PHP source code:
#
#AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

Вот и посмотрим, что у вас. Ваш хандлер AddHandler php-cgi -- при чём ругается на его отсутствие. В связи с этим у меня вопросы: а откуда вы копировали эти строки, хотите ли вы установить php в режиме cgi или вам всё же нужно установить его как модуль? Ну и до кучи: операционка-то хоть какая?

Comment: В целях самообразования: разве PHP CLI это не среда для выполнения PHP в терминале?

Comment: @smellyshovel Спасибо, что заметили ошибку. Поправил текст.

Comment: @smellyshovel cli - да, командная строка.